# Search all words with no vowels

Tags: regex, powershell

I have got a file "dic.txt" and I need to search all word which contains no vowels.

```
$dic = gc "dic.txt"
$v = @("aeiou")
foreach ($line in $dic){$line | ?{$_ -notcontains $v}}
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$dic = gc "dic.txt"

foreach ($line in $dic)
{
    $line | ? { $_ -notmatch 'a|e|i|o|u' }
}
```

Comment: I forgot the "y" letter :- )

Answer (score 0):

If you have one word on each line, something like this:

```
Select-String '(?i)^(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z-])+$' 'dic.txt'
```

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` makes it case-insensitive
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z])` matches one letter that is not `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u`
- `+` repeats that one or more times
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: Maybe is not the case of the OP but in case of "composed word" like `spy-story` it fails.

Comment: @CB You mean that it matches `spy` because it has no vowels? You're right, and you're also right that maybe that's exactly what expirat001 wants, or maybe not. Let us know, expirat0001. :)

Comment: no, I mean that it matches `spy-story` and it has the vowel `o` ... try a little test and you'll see what I mean..

Comment: @CB It doesn't match `story`, why would it? See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/46)

Comment: @CB You're right. I'm sure you know this but for the record the behavior is not about the regex but about `grep`, which returns the entire line where if finds a match, and `spy` is a match. Assuming we have one word per line, changed the regex so the words are fully anchored. Good catch, thank you. :)