# How to match words with no vowel?

Tags: python, regex

The world of vowel and around could be subjective, so I've these set of rules:

- A vowel is any of a, e, i, o, u. Not y.
- A word is a sequence of English language letters, a-z, A-Z.
- `\n`, `,` (comma), `.` (period) or  (space) are not part of the word.

I have following string:

```
text = """line with every word a vowel
sntshk xx yy.
Okay zz fine."""
```

My try:

```
s = re.findall(r'[^aeiouAEIOU].*', text)
print(s)
```

Expectation:

```
['sntshk', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz']
```

Reality:

```
['line with every word a vowel', '\nsntshk xx yy.', '\nOkay zz fine.']
```

Related: [Search all words with no vowels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24607849/939986)

Comment: should it match strings like `hhh_111` or `hh111` ?

Comment: Nope, see the definition of a word above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an ordinary character set composed of alphabetical characters, excluding the vowels, with word boundaries at each end:

```
(?i)\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/DqGuY1/1

- `(?i)` - Case-insensitive match
- `\b` - Word boundary
- `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]+` - Repeat one or more of:

  - characters in the range of `b-d`, or `f-h`, or `j-n`, or `p-t`, or `v-z`
- `\b` - Word boundary

More readably, but less elegantly, you could also use

```
(?i)\b(?:(?![eiou])[b-z])+\b
```

Comment:  what the.. was that? Would you care to explain?

Comment: A dash inside a character set will match any characters in the range from the character on the left of the dash, to the character on the right. Eg `[a-c]` will match `a`, `b`, or `c`, I just continued the pattern and excluded vowels

Comment: Can you also explain `(?:(?![eiou])[b-z])` bit?

Comment: It matches a character between `b` and `z`, while (in the negative lookahead) making sure that the matched character is not in the character set of `[eiou]`

Comment: I'm still a little confused about `?:` thing. 

Comment: Non-capturing group. It's like a capturing group (plain parentheses `(stuff)`) except that the text matched inside is not retained for later use. Unless you *need* a capturing group, best to use a non-capturing group, for ordinary logical grouping

Comment: I would say `(?i)\b(?:(?![eiou])[b-z])+\b` is *less* readable but perhaps more elegant.

Answer (score 2):

I would just target using the pattern `\b[^AEIOU_0-9\W]+\b` in case insensitive mode:

```
text = """line with every word a vowel
sntshk xx yy.
Okay zz fine."""

re.findall(r'\b[^AEIOU_0-9\W]+\b', text, flags=re.I)
print(s)

['sntshk', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz']
```

The pattern `[^\W]` in fact is a double negative, and means any word character.  To this negative class we blacklist off vowels, digits, and underscore, leaving only consonants.

Comment: you should add `_` and `\d` also in negated character class else it will match `hhh_111` or `hhh_www` or `hh111`

Answer (score 1):

```
[^aeiouAEIOU]
```

This means match anything except `aeiouAEIOU` so it will match characters other than alphabets too which is not required as you want to get words only,

so simply match all the alphabets other than vowels

```
\b[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]+\b
```

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/IWvdVF/1/)

Comment: Simplest of all responses. 

Answer (score 1):

There is a pure Python way you can do this without any imports:

```
[x.strip('.') for x in text.split() if all(y.lower() not in 'aeiou' for y in x)]
```

**Example**:

```
text = """line with every word a vowel 
sntshk xx yy.
Okay zz fine."""

print([x.strip('.') for x in text.split() if all(y.lower() not in 'aeiou' for y in x)])
# ['sntshk', 'xx', 'yy', 'zz']
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
text = """line with every word a vowel
sntshk xx yy.
Okay zz fine."""
q = ''
s = text.split()
for i in range(len(s)):
    c = 0
    s[i] = s[i].strip('.')
    for c in range(len(s[i])):
        if (s[i])[c].lower() in 'aeiou':
            q += s[i]+' '
            break
print(q)
```